# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined with Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some problems with sencha touch.
I have this simple code :

```
items: [
        {
            name: "horo",
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            label: 'Horodateur ?',
            labelWidth: '55%',
            disabled: false,
            listeners: {
                beforechange: function (slider, thumb, newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1) {
                        alert("toto");
                    }
                },
                change: function (slider, thumb, newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1) {
                        alert("titi");
                    }
                    else if (oldValue == 1 && newValue == 0)
                        alert("tata");
                }
            }
        },
```

And I have this error on my console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.

What's the problem ?
My console say something else, maybe the `Controller.js` is the problem.

Comment: Many times I see that error when either the xtype doesn't exist, or I'm calling a function that doesn't exist (like if I have a typo in the function name).

Comment: Use Google Chrome's DevTools. Set "Pause on Exception" in your "Sources" tab, and then walk back up the call stack to see where the problem originates.

Comment: I had code win.callback(win, {}); for a dialog window, and fixed it by using win.close().  Not sure if you have similar code that's not displayed here?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a complete example to fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: I back up Peter. More code. Otherwise this cannot be solved

Comment: Sometimes you can see errors like this if you add items to a component in the initComponent() method. In some cases if you move the callParent(); call above where you are adding the items error will be resolved.

Comment: Check the Developer's console and look at the stacktrace

Comment: try requires: ['Ext.field.Toggle'] just in case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
This problem can occur when you define some listeners and you did not define the function in your controller. 
I can see that beforechange and change have functions so maybe there are more items in your code that you have not shown here in the forum. If there are listeners and the listener referer to a function that do not exist then you will get an error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"